# Mesh modeling - remove parts of a mesh using a uv map

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design, software

Any idea which software they use to get the honeycomb pattern?

I just read a nice article about the “Design of a Patient Specific, 3D printed Arm Cast”. (https://knepublishing.com/index.php/KnE-Engineering/article/view/607/1895)

To create the cast model itself is pretty simple but I found no easy way to remove the honeycombs.

The article just says:

"Using the solid body model that was extruded from the surface of the arm, the pattern can be applied to the cast model. This is done by creating a UV map of the models surface and creating a surface mask of the pattern, this is applied to the model. Using the design mask the areas that not required can be removed from the cast model."

But it is not mentioned which software they use. Maybe someone of you got an idea.

[image]

Comment: Solid works is used to create such designs . But its more easily done on 3DS max .